# Converting a simple Excel macro to LibreOffice Calc BASIC macro

Tags: excel, vba, libreoffice-basic

I want to run the below Excel VBA code in LibreOffice BASIC on a Raspberry PI, what results in a BASIC-runtime-error '423' Cells. If I run the same VBA code on a different version of LibreOffice Calc (desktop version), it actually does work.

I already know that BASIC has limited support for VBA statements (`Option VBASupport 1`). Probably, the desktop LibreOffice has more support, therefore it does work there and not on the Raspberry Pi. I also see that the error results from this line of code: `eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row`.

What the code does is, it searches for the next empty row of a table and prints the values I have written in X3 - X9. X10 is the amount of repetitions, because it's for an assignment list that needs a new row for every repetition.

```
Rem Attribute VBA_ModuleType=VBAModule
Option VBASupport1
Sub findnextemptyrow
Dim x As Integer
eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
For x = eRow to eRow + Range("X10") - 1
Cells(x, 1).Value = Range("X3")
Cells(x, 2).Value = Range("X4")
Cells(x, 3).Value = Range("X5")
Cells(x, 4).Value = Range("X6")
Cells(x, 5).Value = Range("X7")
Cells(x, 6).Value = Range("X8")
Cells(x, 7).Value = Range("X9")
```

Since I have not much knowledge about both VBA and BASIC and I would have to delve in both languages. I was hoping this is an easy conversion for someone here. Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Answered at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/253777/converting-a-simple-excel-vba-macro-to-libreoffice-calc-basic-macro/.

Answer (score 0):

The function `GetLastUsedRow()` in the 'Tools' macro library will find the last used row in the *entire sheet*. So the solution posted on [ask.libreoffice.org](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/253777/converting-a-simple-excel-vba-macro-to-libreoffice-calc-basic-macro/) will either insert the new data in the first row after the end of your table, as desired, OR in the first row after the end of your column of source data, whichever is the greater. If your table is shorter than your column of source data then there will be a gap between the last row of the table and the first row of the block of new data. You could avoid this possibility by putting your source data in a row instead of a column. This also makes setting the data array a bit simpler. The following sub assumes the source data are in a row beginning at cell X1:

```
Sub findnextemptyrow

Dim oSheet As Object
oSheet = ThisComponent.Sheets.getByName ("Sheet1")

Globalscope.BasicLibraries.LoadLibrary("Tools")
Dim nEndRow As Integer
nEndRow = GetLastUsedRow(oSheet)

Dim eRow as Integer
eRow = nEndRow + 1

'Source data contained in the row beginning at X1
Dim oSourceData As Object
oSourceData = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("X1:AF1").getDataArray()

'Number of rows to insert is in cell AG1
Dim nRowsToInsert As Integer
nRowsToInsert = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("AG1").getCellByPosition(0, 0).getValue() 

Dim u as Integer
u =  UBound(oSourceData(0))

Dim i As Integer, oReceptorRange As Object
For i = eRow To eRow + nRowsToInsert - 1    
    oReceptorRange = oSheet.getCellRangeByPosition(0, i, u, i)
    oReceptorRange.setDataArray(oSourceData)      
Next i

End Sub
```

AFAIK LibreOffice / OpenOffice doesn't have a programmatic way of finding the last non-empty row in a range of cells smaller than a whole sheet, such as a single column, for example. This is because the function `gotoEndOfUsedArea()` of a `SheetCellCursor` object always goes to the end of the used area of the whole sheet, even if the cursor was derived from a `SheetCellRange` object smaller than the whole sheet. This may not necessarily be the intended behaviour, i.e. it may be a bug.